# How to run spring boot application with Multiple External Configuration Files based on jars

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I am having 3 spring boot projects. [Demo1, Demo2 and Demo3 .]

Demo1 is the base project.

For Demo2 and Demo3, I will generate the jar and add it in the Demo1 project.

So Demo1, Demo2 and Demo3  all three projects have different application.properties under profiles.

For example,

Demo2 might have oracle database configuration under application.properties.
Demo3 might have mongodb database configuration under application.properties

Demo1 might have mysql database configuration under application.properties.

My scenario is like, I am creating a scheduler platform application.

N no of jars will come and add under Demo1 project. So the Demo1 project will automatically run based on cron expressions.

It will automatically trigger the jars which you have added.

So if the call is going for Demo2 Project, it has to pick Demo2 application properties.

If the call is going for Demo3 Project, It has to pick Demo3 application properties.

Right now the Demo1 project is not recognizing the application.properties for different jars.

Only Demo2 project application.properties is loading, Demo1 and Demo3 properties are not loaded.

I need a solution for my scenario.

Comment: My pom file : <dependency>
<groupId>com.demo2</groupId>
<artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.demo3</groupId>
<artifactId>demo3</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>  My Application file:


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { 
  "com.demo2.*", "com.demo3.*","com.demo1.*"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
     "com.demo2.*", "com.demo3.*","com.demo1.*"
})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
  "com.demo2.*", "com.demo3.*","com.demo1.*"
})
public class Demo1Application

Comment: It's not really clear to me, can you elaborate on what you mean by "if the call is going for Demo N Project" ?? What call? What do the jars contain? Just data layer code? The architecture context is missing  I think.

Comment: @Hermann Steidel
Yeah it's a data layer code. Jars would contain the functional implementation. That would interact with the database.

Comment: So the demo2 and demo3 jar are always deployed with demo1? My point is, is it possible to run Demo1 and only use Demo3, while someone else used Demo1 and Demo2 only? Or is Demo1 always going to utilize Demo2 and Demo3 based on the "call" (whatever that is)?

Comment: All the clarifications including the pom code should be added to the initial post (use edit). Please see the guide [ask].

Comment: Demo1 is the base project. N no of projects will come and add as a jar under Demo1 project. The demo1 project is like a scheduler platform. This project will automatically triggers and picks the corresponding jar based on some logical condition. My issue is how to deal with application.properties when we have multiple jars. Each jars might have different configurations. When ever if base projects picks demo2 application it has to load his application.properties. similar to remaining jar as well